# MapKit is black when i put it in tab bar

Tags: ios, swift

I want the map page in tab bar , but the map shows as a black page when i run the app!
However when i placed the map in first view it showed normally  , i do not know the reason of that when I move it to tab bar controller it become black ! , my Xcode version is  8.2.1 with swift 3 and this is my code :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class MapPage: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!



    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations[0]
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01,0.01)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        print(location.altitude)
        print(location.speed)

        self.map.showsUserLocation = true

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

[this is the first view when i run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDTjE.png)

[here is when i put the map in the tab bar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UcES.png)

Comment: As it works without a TabBar (how I understood), I suspect the error is in your tabbar configuration, which you did not post any information about.

Comment: Sounds like your main.Storyboard is messed up. What do you mean by the first view? The first tab?

Comment: i mean with first view the first view when i run my application

Comment: As shallowThought said this sounds like an issue with your tab bar configuration. You need to post the code and if you're using a Storyboard a screenshot or two as that's where it sounds like the issue is. Try using the visual view debugging tool to ensure your mapview is actually on screen and you're not just looking at a plain black view.